# Create a block with a template in my own module

Tags: magento2, blocks

I am attempting to create a block with a template in my own module.  When I come to view the website (front end) I get an HTTP 500 error (admin side still loads). I have checked in the var/log folder for any debug or system messages but none are reported. Disabling the module allows the website to load again.

Below are the steps, along with file directories and file content for what I have done.

My Magento 2 main directory is *StoreTest*

**Registering a module** (I successfully did this stage but I will include it for clarity)

Created module.xml and registration.php in the following folders.

StoreTest/Code/Mymodules/Mybanner/etc/module.xml
StoreTest/Code/Mymodules/Mybanner/registration.php

Module.xml content

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     *
     * @category    mymodules
     * @package     mymodules_mybanner
     * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 mymodules
     * @license     none
     */
    -->
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="mymodules_mybanner" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
    </config>
```

Registration.php content

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'mymodules_mybanner',
    __DIR__
);
```

Registered the module (by logging into the server using PuTTy and navigating to the StoreTest/bin/ directory)

```
php magento module:enable mymodules_mybanner
```

Then I ran

```
php magento setup:upgrade
```

**Create a Block, layout and template file.**

To create a block I added a MyBlock.php file to the following location
StoreTest/app/code/Mymodules/Mybanner/Block/

MyBlock.php content

```
<?php

namespace Mymodules\Mybanner\Block;

class MyBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Return the HTML
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHtmlString()
    {
        return "Testing";
    }
}
```

I created a layout file called cms_index_index.xml in the following location
StoreTest/app/code/Mymodules/Mybanner/view/frontend/layout/

cms_index_index.xml content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @category    Mymodules
 * @package     mymodules_mybanner
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magestore (http://www.magestore.com/)
 * @license     http://www.magestore.com/license-agreement.html
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="main">
           <block class="Mymodules\Mybanner\Block\MyBlock" name="mybanner.example" template="banner.phtml" >
                <action method="getHtmlString" />
           </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Lastly I created a banner.phtml file in the following location
StoreTest/app/code/Mymodules/Mybanner/view/frontend/templates/

Banner.phtml content

```
<?php 
/*
  * @var \Mymodules\Mybanner\Block\MyBlock $block 
*/ 
?>
<h3>Howdy folks!</h3>
<p><?php echo $block->getHtmlString(); ?></p>
```

My folder structure looks like the following

```
StoreTest
|-- Mymodules
    |-- Mybanner
        |-- Block
        |    |--MyBlock.php
        |-- etc
        |    |--module.xml
        |-- view
        |    |-- frontend
        |         |-- layout
        |              |--cms_index_index.xml
        |         |-- templates
        |              |-- banner.phtml 
        |-- registration.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to check:

**Namespace**

Module.xml & registration.php you have:

```
<module name="mymodules_mybanner"
```

and you enabled module:

```
php magento module:enable mymodules_mybanner
```

but in MyBlock.php you are calling the Module block via:

```
namespace Mymodules\Mybanner\Block;
```

and in cms_index_index.xml you are rendering block:

```
<block class="Mymodules\Mybanner\Block\MyBlock"
```

Notice the capitalization discrepancies within the namespace. Please correct these.

**Deploy your static content**

After correcting the namespace and enabling the module, run setup:upgrade again.
Then run:

```
php magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have done the requested changes. Unfortunately I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: Hmmm i would double check to ensure your files/folders are all named appropriately.

Comment: I delete the module and started again with the advice you gave me. It works. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear Scott. Please accept my answer,  marking your question answered. Thanks.